# How to find and replace text in a Word DOCX file that contains a table, using Python

Tags: python, cpu-word

I have a Word DOCX that contains a table and by using Python script I want to find-and-replace specific text. So far any solution I found and tried did not work.
Here is a sample screenshot of my Word DOCX that I am working on
[image]

I would like to replace the text **to_be_replaced** with something else.
Can someone please help me out? Thank you

Comment: Try looking at [Replace text in docx tables in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40369351/replace-text-in-docx-tables-in-python-3).

Comment: @Cartellano I have seen this solution before but unfortunately I could not figure out the right coding for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more surfing I finally found the source code that works like a charm!!!

[Python docx Replace string in paragraph while keeping style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779724/python-docx-replace-string-in-paragraph-while-keeping-style/55733040#55733040)

The code snipet that I used and worked for me was the answer by:

[image]

The Word docx I used contained tables and images and the code just replaced the words I wanted, without changing anything else in the document. Really good work by **CG Zhang**. I hope my answer helps others too.